# What Greek or IE god or goddess was named "Da"?

Tags: greek

[This answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/11202/624) claims that the etymology of the name of Greek goddess Demeter is "mother of Da" and the etymology of Poseidon is "husband of Da".
Who is Da then?

PS. I seems to be a variant of γῆ?

Comment: The etymologies of Demeter and Poseidon are unclear. One suggestion is that Δῆ/Δᾶ is indeed the Doric form of Γῆ (earth). There's a lot of information on the subject on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demeter#Etymology & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poseidon#Etymology

Answer (score 2):

The form *Gdan-Ma* (conventionally taken to mean "Earth Mother") is attested in Phrygian, so it's been suggested that Classical Greek *Gā/Gē* and Mycenaean *Da* are different ways of simplifying a Pre-Greek (so probably non-Indo-European) name that didn't fit perfectly into Greek phonology.

In other words, according to this theory, "Da" is an alternate name of Gaea, the earth personified.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a translation issue, but without the original verse it's impossible to verify.

> δα– intens. Prefix, = ζα-, as in δάσκιος, δαφοινός.
>
> δάσκιος ον, (< δα, σκιά) thick-shaded, bushy, ὕλη Od. 5.470, B. 10.93, etc. ; ὄρη E. Ba. 218 ; γενειάς A. Pers. 316, S. Tr. 13.
>
> δαφοινός όν (ή, όν Opp. C. 3.440 ; δαφοινή as etym. of δάφνη in Corn. ND 32), epith. of savage animals

in the 2 examples δα is a prefix that elevates the following word to its superlative. So likely in the verse referred to in the other answer it's "Great Mother" (Doric: Δαμάτηρ Dāmā́tēr), not "Mother of da".

Comment: https://lsj.gr/wiki/%CE%B4%E1%BE%B6 may be more helpful than  https://lsj.gr/wiki/%CE%B4%CE%B1-